# EventCrtOffCode doesn't get set when calling CRMEventAdd

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

When creating a CustCon event using CRMEventAdd, I'm assigning the CRMEventInfoRec.EventCrtOffCode to a valid officer but the contact event *Created By* user does not get set to the value I'm sending in the request.
The *Created By* value shows the jXchange user.
The same is true when setting the same property in CRMEventMod.

How can I change the *Created By* user in my CRMEventAdd request?
Does EventCrtOffCode do something besides set the Created By officer?

```
request.CustId = new SynapsysCustomer.CustId_Type() { Value = custId };
request.CRMEventType = new SynapsysCustomer.CRMEventType_Type() { Value = "CustCon" };
request.CRMEventInfoRec = new SynapsysCustomer.CRMEventInfoRec_CType();
request.CRMEventInfoRec.CRMEventDt = new SynapsysCustomer.CRMEventDt_Type() { Value = DateTime.Today };
request.CRMEventInfoRec.EventCatCode = new SynapsysCustomer.EventCatCode_Type() { Value = "313" };
request.CRMEventInfoRec.EventStatCode = new SynapsysCustomer.EventStatCode_Type() { Value = "28" };
request.CRMEventInfoRec.RmndSchedEnable = new SynapsysCustomer.RmndSchedEnable_Type() { Value = "true" };
request.CRMEventInfoRec.EventOffCode = new SynapsysCustomer.CRMOffCode_Type() { Value = "OFFCODE" };
request.CRMEventInfoRec.EventCrtOffCode = new SynapsysCustomer.CRMOffCode_Type() { Value = "OFFCODE" };

response = await client.CRMEventAddAsync(request);
```

The contact event gets created with the *Assigned To* set to OFFCODE but the *Created By* shows as the jXchange user, not OFFCODE.

Answer (score 0):

We reached out to the our Synapsys support team with your question. Here is their response:

> The `EventCrtOffCode` element is part of the Event suite of services, but is only supported on the `CRMEventInq` service to return the officer who created the event.
>
> When an event is created via `CRMEventAdd`, `EventCrtOffCode` is ignored and the officer derived from the header is used since that is who sent the request.